# Selenium Best Practices: Write scenario logic in C# or inject javascript script that contains the logic and test the page

Tags: javascript, selenium, architecture, webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and i would like to hear the answers of other more experienced developers.

My question is related to what is the best approach when designing an Automation Application for a web application using Selenium.

We have two options:

**Option 1.** Write a C# App (i choose C# as development language, doesn't matter if is Java or another) on top of Selenium WebDriver. The C# App will have the scenarios logic written in C# and is using selenium methods (to click on DOM elements, read text, select, etc). Only from time to time, when needed, insert small pieces of JavaScript code and do some actions.

**Option 2.** Write a C# App on top of Selenium Webdriver. This app will be responsible of injecting JavaScript files into the correct page. All the scenario logic will be written in the JavaScript file. Basically use Selenium for script injection, reading the script result and that's pretty much it.

The Automation tool will be responsible of testing several Web Applications, some JavaScript SDK (sample pages that use this SDK). The Application will have to test events triggered, DOM content, etc.

Which approach would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly oppose option 2 where you are injecting javascript into browser. Injecting JS changes scope of your application and your application would not behave exactly how it would otherwise for your users. Hence you are not exactly testing the applications your users are using. Here are some points,

1. When Selenium RC was initially created, it would inject javascripts in the browser and provide you methods in different bindings to interact with the elements. Over the period, all these shortcomings of this approach were addressed and WebDriver was born. Your approach of injecting JS is regressive and wouldn't help you much.
2. Writing JS for simulating browser interactions will take some effort and maintenance and brittleness will be a nightmare. *Why invent the wheel?*
3. WebDriver uses browsers native APIs and becoming (or already?) a W3C standard. It simulates browser interactions exactly like how a real user would interact with your application
4. Lastly I would vote you choose the same WebDriver bindings as your application. This way you can write tests in the same language as your application and tests can live closer to the code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! After reading more i can say that i agree to what you said.